# How can I check in Drupal 8 an externally set $_COOKIE?

Tags: 8

I would like to check whether a Cookie exists, and if so, get the value. But it looks like Drupal is blind to external cookies that have not been set inside Drupal.

```
$mycookie = \Drupal::request()->cookies->all();
```

Returns an array with only the Drupal cookies, and I can see in my web browser that there are more (some that I am interested in and I can't modify he app that is creating those cookies). I remember there was a similar issue with Symfony 2 and session but I can't find it...

Comment: Are the cookies of the same origin?

Comment: @mradcliffe They are created in a different host than the one I have Drupal running, (they are actually Mautic cookies and I'm trying to to do that "https://www.mautic.org/community/index.php/2985-get-data-from-mautic/0" - oh wow now I realize I might have asked in the wrong place or wrong question...) Is it possible to get those cookies?

Comment: See if this applies to your situation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_data_storage_access

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is nothing Drupal-specific. You can always only access cookies from the same origin. You can't access cookies from other origins. Imagine if that were possible. I could then write a web application that would harvest your gmail cookies, and log into your gmail remotely to do whatever I like.

Answer (score 1):

For external cookies please try with $_COOKIE['cookie_name'].

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie_name'])) {
  print($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
}
```

The code will print out the value of the cookie if present.

For a more specific answer please explain your question.Ty!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86415)

Comment: Please see the first sentence:"I would like to check whether a Cookie exists, and if so, get the value."
The: $_COOKIE['cookie_name'] will return the value if exits.
Also there is no clear question here, and no question mark.
It is very easy to put -1.

Comment: I think that you need to improve your question, maybe with an explanation about why this is the good solution

Comment: I not the downvoter but I'm sure that the downvote was because this site is for learning, and you need to explain a little your answer.

Comment: My opinion is that you should encourage good responses not take away people's binge.

Comment: Arnold my comment comes from a system review, I'm not write this message for you, when you got more rep you will see how this works.

Comment: I see you edit, its now better, I think that you need to take the tour: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: This doesn't work. You can only access cookies from the same origin where they've been set.